# C# Asynchronous HTTPWebRequest on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I am new to .Net and Windows Phone development. I am currently investigating different ways for making asynchronous web requests through HTTPWebrequest class.

**Async and Await:**

async and await seems to be a neat way for making asynchronous web requests: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html. My only concern is, according to the documentation, calling method thread would be suspended while the Task is executed. I want the calling method to return immediately, how do I do it?

```
public async Task NewStuffAsync()
{
  // Use await and have fun with the new stuff.
  await ...
}

public Task MyOldTaskParallelLibraryCode()
{
  // Note that this is not an async method, so we can't use await in here.
  ...
}

public async Task ComposeAsync()
{
  // We can await Tasks, regardless of where they come from.
  await NewStuffAsync();
  await MyOldTaskParallelLibraryCode();
}
```

**HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse**

Here is an example from Microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

I would like to understand the overhead associated with the callbacks.

**ThreadPool**

Managed ThreadPool seems to be robust. Once again I would like to understand the overhead associated with it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx

Comment: If you compile your code given that you are using `HttpWebRequest`, you will get a warning that this class is obsolete. As suggested use the `HttpClient`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually have been experimenting with this. I posted the code so you can play around with it. There is actually a difference when using `async`/`await` and using callback. `async`/`await` flows more naturally for me.

Consider the following code. It's a console app by the way. Both codes achieve the same thing.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MakeRequest();       

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async void MakeRequest()
    {
        await UseHttpClient();
        UseWebClient();
    }

    private static async Task UseHttpClient()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== HttpClient ==");
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        Console.WriteLine("HttpClient requesting...");
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.Substring(0,100));
        Console.WriteLine("HttpClient done");
    }

    private static void UseWebClient()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("=== WebClient ==");
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        Console.WriteLine("WebClient requesting...");
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => Console.WriteLine(eventArgs.Result.Substring(0,100));
        Console.WriteLine("WebClient done.");
    }
```

And these are the outputs:

For `HttpClient`

```
=== HttpClient ==
HttpClient requesting...
<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head><meta itemprop
HttpClient done
```

For `WebClient`which uses callback

```
=== WebClient ==
WebClient requesting...
WebClient done.
<!doctype html><html itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
<head><meta itemprop
```

As you can see, `HttpClient` actually await the result first before continuing with the flow (it actually returns back to the caller). Thus, the keyword `await`, it awaits and later execute.

But the flow is totally different when using callback. You code flows continuously (that's why you can see `WebClient done` is printed before the actual result. In order to achieve the same flow as async/await, there are multiple of ways. One of them is making use of the TCS and wrap your function around it (I won't cover here as this has been covered multiple times). The easiest way is to use `HttpClient`.

Hope it helps understanding between `async`/`await` and using callback.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend install the [Microsoft.Net.Http](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) NuGet Package and using the HttpClient. This has async await support built in.

Answer (score 0):

> My only concern is, according to the documentation, calling method thread would be suspended while the Task is executed.

No; with `async`/`await`, you can think of it like this: the *method* is suspended, but the *thread* returns and continues running. So the UI remains responsive.

As Blounty suggested, check out `HttpClient` in the `Microsoft.Net.Http` package (currently in RC).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found this and helped me

```
private async Task<T> ExecuteAsync<T>(RestRequest request)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
    _client.ExecuteAsync(request, resp =>
    {
        var value = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resp.Content);
        if (value.ErrorCode > 0)
        {
            var ex = new ToodledoException(value.ErrorCode, value.ErrorDesc);
            tcs.SetException(ex);
        }
        else
            tcs.SetResult(value);
    });
    return await tcs.Task;
}
```

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Asynchronous_Programming_For_Windows_Phone_8 also I found this extension helpful http://nuget.org/packages/WP8AsyncWebClient/